# Нужно ли подписывать refresh JWT token или достаточно отдать пользователю его UUID?

Tags: веб-программирование, http, jwt

Нужно ли подписывать шифровать refresh JWT token (в общем делать тоже что и с access токеном)или достаточно отдать пользователю его UUID?

Comment: Делать нужно то, что помешает злоумышленнику получить несанкционированный доступ. А что конкретно при этом делать — уже ваше личное дело, лишь бы это действительно что-то защищало

Comment: Если вы собрались использовать UUID пользователя, то вам нужно тщательно убедиться, что этот UUID нигде не публикуется (например, в профиле пользователя), чтобы злоумышленник не мог прочитать его и использовать в качестве токена. Кроме того, имейте в виду, что в случае, если злоумышленник каким-то образом украдёт токен с устройства пользователя, то должна быть возможность сделать его недействительным — сможете ли вы сделать недействительным украденный UUID пользователя?

Comment: @andreymal, схема немного другая, при создании токенов, создается access_token и refresh_token с мета информацией, этому refresh_token присваивается UUID и EXP, refresh_token записывается в базу. При запросе на refresh, приходит UUID, токен достается из базы, проверяет не истекло ли время, если не истекло, то удаляется из базы и создается пара новых токенов, refresh записывается в базу, а refresh_uuid и access отдаются пользователю

Comment: Ну если токен нельзя подделать или повторно использовать, то значит, наверное, всё хорошо. Правда, остаётся вопрос — если refresh-токен всё равно записывается в базу, то зачем вообще делать его в виде JWT? Можно точно так же в базе записать UUID и EXP, refresh-токен сделать просто случайными буковками к примеру, а при его проверке проверять UUID и EXP из базы. Насколько я понимаю, многие сайты именно так и делают (на английском Stack Overflow прямо так и пишут: [refresh-токен — это просто случайная строка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56133083))

Comment: @andreymal, да да, про это я и спрашивал, refresh не пишется в виде jwt, все так как вы сказали, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если вы планируете хранить refresh токен в базе данных, вы можете создать его в виде uuid, чтобы убедиться в его уникальности. Это может быть полезно для отслеживания и обновления токена при необходимости. Если вы не планируете хранить refresh токен в базе данных и хотите использовать формат JWT, вы можете создать его с более длительным сроком действия и не хранить в БД.